# WPF more then one DataTrigger

Tags: wpf

Would you know why the XAML below is not working. It looks like I can not have more than one DataTrigger for an element. Those Storyboards within DataTrigger, as you can tell are being executed on a button click. 
The end reason is that on a button click, one grid should slide up, and the other slide down, achieving sort of accordian animation. Thanks

```html
           <StackPanel Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <!--Add New Banner Grid-->
                <!--<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="#FFE0FFD2" Height="50">-->
                <Grid x:Name="grdAddBunner">
                    <Grid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE0FFD2"></Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnEditBunner, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="150" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"></DoubleAnimation>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnAddBunner, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="150" Duration="0:0:0.5"></DoubleAnimation>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                </DataTrigger>

                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Style>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="Add New Banner" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkGreen" FontWeight="Bold"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Fund"></Label>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding LstFund}"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Banner"></Label>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" Margin="3" Text="{Binding AddBannerName}"></TextBox>
                        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="Save" Command="{Binding AddBannerCmd}" Height="25" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Button>
                        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Content="Calcel" Height="25" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <!--Edit Existing Banner Grid-->
                <!--<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="#FFFFF7D2" Height="50">-->
                    <Grid x:Name="grdEditBanner">
                    <Grid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFF7D2"></Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnAddBunner, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="150" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"></DoubleAnimation>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnEditBunner, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="150" Duration="0:0:0.5"></DoubleAnimation>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                </DataTrigger>

                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Style>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="Edit Existing Banner" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF5B6400" FontWeight="Bold"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Fund"></Label>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding LstFund}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBannerFund}"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Banner"></Label>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" Margin="3" Text="{Binding SelectedBannerName}"></TextBox>
                        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="Save" Command="{Binding UpdateBannerCmd}" Height="25" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Button>
                        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Content="Calcel" Height="25" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Actually DataTriggers are fine in here. I have just noticed that the Height property is not being saved, on button release the height is being reverted to the original value.

Comment: The "IsPressed" lets you know when the button is "active" this changes again when you release the button. So this will only be set to true while you have the button depressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "IsPressed" lets you know when the button is "active" this changes again when you release the button.

Have you tried moving this to a command binding on the button and set properties on your viewModel that those grids can use to set styles on themselves?

Comment: Yes, it works that way. Good suggestion. Is there a way to capture 'IsClicked' instead of 'IsPressed' with DataTrigger?

Comment: Yes, that would be a "Event Trigger". I hope this helps.